# Create View with 2 rows of diferent Content

Tags: views

Can someone help me on whow can i create a View Like This?
I Found this view a a theme template at http://demo.megadrupal.com/?theme=md-thenews .

This view is composed by 2 rows. The first one has an image, a title and a teaser and the other rows has a list of articles.
I've also tried the views_field_view plugin, but the output is not the same.
Thanks for you help.

[image: View With 2 rows]

Code behind the view in the image:

```
<div class="view view-category-news view-id-category_news view-display-id-block_1 
 view-dom-id-9b65677b6b3b4229321f21719157d144 view-content">
  <div class="rows-first rows-inner row">
        .... //Views Fields
  </div>
  <div class="rows-others rows-inner">
    .... //Views Fields
  </div>
</div
```

Comment: create two views (say A and B) The first view will have  image, a title and a teaser then create a second view which contain list of articles ,create both the view as block type ,then render both block type view into the same region or in the same div ...rest of ur work css will do

Comment: Thankyou for your answer. I've ha already tried your aproach, but what i need is a litte bit diferent. I just want to have one view like the image above.
They managed to to that, and i woul like to know how they dit it.

Comment: u can achieve this by adding 4 or 5  body field In ur content type ,place the links into that body fields after that u can show ur view as given in image, after applying some css code

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because implementing a functionality or a layout seen in a site, for which just a description of the feature, a screenshot, or a site URL is provided [is defined as thing you should not ask here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Sorry for the that, but i just put link to help understanding what oi want to achieve.

Comment: As you can see, "just a description" is off-topic as well, link and screenshot or no link and screenshot.

Comment: i think in right coloum related links of the node  are comming means Node reference field

Comment: What will be relation of  first(having teaser view) and the second(displaying only title). What is the relation among them?

Comment: High level answer is to add the additional fields required for the first row and exclude them from display, then manually print them for the first row by overriding views templates in your theme.

Answer (score 2):

[Views Node Split](https://drupal.org/project/views_nodes_split) module does what you are trying to achieve.

> This module allows site administrators or builders to have a different view mode for the first nodes of a view result